# How to run tasks in a fixed thread pool

Tags: java, parallel-processing, threadpoolexecutor

I'm writing a network simulator and I want all the routers route methods to run in parallel. I have an ExecutorSercive of type fixedThreadpool. The idea is to loop over the the routers submitting a new task to the service for each router. For some reason the service seems to only starting one task. I'm not sure if this is an issue with the way I'm calling it. I see other people online using service.execute(). I'm just getting started with parallel programing. Thank you in advance.

```
    var clock = new SimpleClock();
    network.setClock(clock);
    var routers = network.allRouters();
    do{
      clock.step();
      Semaphore routing = new Semaphore( 0 );
      for( Router r : routers ){
        service.execute(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            r.route();
            routing.release();
          }
        });
        try {
          routing.acquire( routers.size() );
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }while( network.isActive() );
  }
```

Comment: At first glance I'd think the code would do what you described if you just removed the routing semaphore.
What were you trying to acomplish with the Semaphore?

Comment: Oh that Semaphore was meant to be outside the for loop. I wanted route to be called on all routers, then wait for them all to finish, then to call some other methods. I feel stupid now. Thank you for your help. I was looking at that for too long.

Comment: I see. If you still need to do extra things after all routers processed, TheadPoolExecutor would have a built-in solution for that. The method invokeAll takes a collection of callable and waits until all were processed before proceeding. Maybe this becomes handy at some point